# React map rerenders after markers are updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-maps, react-map-gl

I am having issue with google map and it rerenders after the markers are updated. I guess it is because of MarkerF or i don't know . Do anyone know the solution? I had tried several methods and tried to look into stack overflow and manysites but none work is there anyway to it:? Search for  work  in the code to find out how it is rendered. I tried using loadscript but it didn't work so i am using useJsApiLoader now.

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import styles from '../../styles/map.module.css'
import { Avatar, Popover, Tabs } from 'antd';
import { CommentOutlined, CarTwoTone, TwitterOutlined, CarOutlined, SmileOutlined, InfoCircleOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { FloatButton } from 'antd';

import priceMapping from '../../config/priceMapping.json'
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader, Autocomplete, MarkerF, Polyline, Marker } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { setAddress, setDropCords, setPickUpCords } from '../../redux/reducerSlice/rides'
import { getDistance } from 'geolib';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { CustomLogo } from '@/components/Logo';
import { handleLogout } from '../../redux/reducerSlice/users'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Link from 'next/link';


export default function index() {
  const [currentPositionDrop, setCurrentPositionDrop] = useState({})
  const [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState({})
  const { pickUpAddr, pickUpCords, dropAddr, dropCords } = useSelector(state => state.rides)
  const router = useRouter()
  useEffect(() => {
    navigator?.geolocation?.getCurrentPosition(position => setCurrentPosition({ lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude }))
  }, [])
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { isLoaded, loadError } = useJsApiLoader({ libraries: ['places'], googleMapsApiKey: "AIzaSyDLfjmFgDEt9_G2LXVyP61MZtVHE2M3H-0" })
  const containerStyle = {
    width: '70vw',
    height: '95vh'
  };

  const center = { "lat": 27.6854872, "lng": 85.3447924 }
  const handleDragEnd = (e) => {
    const { lat, lng } = e.latLng
    const pickUpCords = { lat: lat(), lng: lng() }
    fetch(`https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/reverse?lat=${pickUpCords.lat}&lon=${pickUpCords.lng}&apiKey=a1dd45a7dfc54f55a44b69d125722fcb`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => dispatch(setAddress({ inputField: data.features[0].properties.formatted, flag: 'pickUpAddr' }))
      )
    setCurrentPosition(pickUpCords)
    dispatch(setPickUpCords(pickUpCords))
  }

  const handleDragEndDest = (e) => {
    debugger;
    const { lat, lng } = e.latLng
    const dropCords = { lat: lat(), lng: lng() }
    fetch(`https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/reverse?lat=${dropCords.lat}&lon=${dropCords.lng}&apiKey=a1dd45a7dfc54f55a44b69d125722fcb`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => dispatch(setAddress({ inputField: data.features[0].properties.formatted, flag: 'dropAddr' }))
      )
    setCurrentPositionDrop(dropCords)
    dispatch(setDropCords(dropCords))
  }


  const onChange = (key) => {
    setTabId(key)
  };

  const FloatBtn = (props) => (
    <>
      <FloatButton.Group
        trigger="hover"
        type="primary"
        style={{
          right: 94,
        }}
        icon={<CommentOutlined />}
      >
        <FloatButton onClick={() => props.setSelectedVehicle('car')} icon={<CarTwoTone />} />
        <FloatButton onClick={() => props.setSelectedVehicle('bike')} icon={<CommentOutlined />} />
      </FloatButton.Group>
    </>
  );

  const MapView = () => {

    const pickUpRef = useRef(null);
    const dropRef = useRef(null);
    const [isEdit, setIsEdit] = useState(false)
    const [isBargained, setIsBargained] = useState(false)
    const [selectedVehicle, setSelectedVehicle] = useState('bike')
    // const handlePickUpChange = ()=> {
    //   dispatch(setAddress({inputField: pickUpRef.current.value, flag:'pickUpAddr'}))
    // }



    const distance = getDistance(
      pickUpCords,
      dropCords
    );
    // const handleDestChange = ()=> {
    //   dispatch(setAddress({inputField: destRef.current.value, flag:'dropAddr'}))
    // }
    const { pricePerUnitKm, basePrice, nightPricePercentile } = priceMapping[selectedVehicle.toLowerCase()]
    const generateCenter = () => {
      if (pickUpCords.lat) {
        return pickUpCords
      } else {
        return center
      }
    }
    const initialPrice = (pricePerUnitKm * (distance / 1000)) + basePrice
    const [bargainedPrice, setbargainedPrice] = useState(Math.ceil(initialPrice))
    const [estimatedPrice, setestimatedPrice] = useState(Math.ceil(initialPrice))
    const handleSetChangePrice = (e) => {

      const estPrice = Number(e.target.textContent)
      if (estPrice > (bargainedPrice - 50)) {
        setbargainedPrice(Number(e.target.textContent))
      } else {
        setbargainedPrice(estimatedPrice)
      }
      setIsBargained(true)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
      setbargainedPrice(Math.ceil(initialPrice))
      setestimatedPrice(Math.ceil(initialPrice))
    }, [selectedVehicle])

    const onLoad = marker => {
      console.log('marker: ', marker)
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <>
          <div className=' grid grid-cols-10 '>
            <div className='h-screen bg-white col-span-3'>
              <Tabs onChange={(text) => setSelectedVehicle(text)} defaultActiveKey="1" items={vehiclesItems} style={{
                background: 'white',
              }} centered={true} />
              <div className='flex justify-center'>
                <div>
                  <div className='pr-4 '>
                    <>
                      {isLoaded && (
                        <>

                          <Autocomplete
                            className='mt-7 py-[15px] px-[10px] w-full border hover:border-[#79BE1D] rounded-[20px]  '
                            onPlaceChanged={handlePickUpChange}
                            key={1}>
                            <input type='text'
                              className='w-full outline-none'
                              ref={pickUpRef}
                              defaultValue={pickUpAddr}
                              placeholder='Pick up address' />
                          </Autocomplete>
                        </>
                      )}


                      {isLoaded && (
                        <>
                          <form>
                            <Autocomplete

                              onPlaceChanged={handleDestChange}
                              key={1}>
                              <input type='text'
                                className='mt-7  w-full border hover:border-[#79BE1D] rounded-[20px]'
                                ref={dropRef}
                                defaultValue={dropAddr}
                                onChange={(e) => dispatch(setAddress({ inputField: e.target.value, flag: 'dropAddr' }))}
                                placeholder='Destination address' />
                            </Autocomplete>
                          </form>
                        </>
                      )}

                    </>
                    <div >
                      <p className='mt-2 mb-2'>
                        Distance: {distance / 1000}  km
                      </p>



                      <div onClick={() => setIsEdit(true)} className='mt-4 mb-4' >
                        <div className='text-gray-500'> Offer your price </div>
                        <div className='mt-2 flex gap-5 justify-center align-top'>
                          <button
                            className='text-black px-3 py-1  rounded-lg bg-black text-white border-2 hover:border-red-700'
                            onClick={() => {
                              if (bargainedPrice <= Math.ceil(initialPrice) - 50) return
                              setbargainedPrice(bargainedPrice - 10)
                              setIsBargained(true)
                            }
                            }

                          >- 10</button>


                          <div className='flex gap-1 hover:cursor-pointer '>
                            <div className='text-green-600 text-xl p-1'>NPR</div>
                            <div className={styles.offer_input} onBlur={handleSetChangePrice} contentEditable={isEdit}>{bargainedPrice} </div>
                          </div>

                          <button onClick={() => {
                            setbargainedPrice(bargainedPrice + 10)
                            setIsBargained(true)
                          }} className=' px-3 py-1   rounded-lg bg-black text-white border-2 hover:border-green-600'>+10 </button>
                        </div>
                        {isBargained && <div className='text-green-600 mt-1 mb-2'  >
                          <InfoCircleOutlined className='relative bottom-1 mr-1 ' />
                          Estimated Price: Rs {estimatedPrice}
                        </div>}
                      </div>

                    </div>
                    <button className='bg-black text-white rounded-lg py-2 px-16  w-10 hover:bg-[#7ABD1F] transition ease-in-out duration-300  flex justify-center mt-5'>
                      Proceed
                    </button>
                  </div>


                  <div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='col-span-7'>
              <div style={{ display: "flex", gap: '2rem' }}>
                {isLoaded ? (
                  <>
                    <GoogleMap
                      mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
                      center={generateCenter()}
                      zoom={15}
                    >
                      <MarkerF
                        draggable={true}
                        onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
                        onLoad={onLoad}
                        position={pickUpCords}
                      />
                      <MarkerF
                        onDragEnd={handleDragEndDest}
                        // icon={"https://web.archive.org/web/20230701011019/https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png"}
                        onLoad={onLoad}
                        draggable={true}
                        position={dropCords}
                      />
                      {/* <FloatBtn /> */}
                      { /* Child components, such as markers, info windows, etc. */}
                      <></>
                    </GoogleMap>
                  </>
                ) : "loading"}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </>

      </div>
    )
  }
  // const UserCard = () => {
  //   const pickUpRef = useRef(null);
  //   const dropRef = useRef(null);

  //   const handlePickUpChange = () => {
  //     dispatch(setAddress({ inputField: pickUpRef.current.value, flag: 'pickUpAddr' }))
  //   }
  //   const handleDestChange = () => {
  //     dispatch(setAddress({ inputField: dropRef.current.value, flag: 'dropAddr' }))
  //   }
  //   const generateCenter = () => {
  //     if (formStep === 1 && currentPosition.lat) {
  //       return currentPosition
  //     } else if (formStep === 2 && currentPositionDrop.lat) {
  //       return currentPositionDrop
  //     } else {
  //       return center
  //     }
  //   }

  //   const onLoad = marker => {


  //     console.log('marker: ', marker)
  //   }
  //   return (
  //     <div>      <div style={{ display: "flex", gap: '2rem' }}>
  //       <div className='pr-4'>
  //         <>
  //           {isLoaded && (
  //             <>

  //               <Autocomplete
  //                 className='mt-7 py-[15px] px-[10px] w-full border hover:border-[#79BE1D] rounded-[20px]  '
  //                 onPlaceChanged={handlePickUpChange}
  //                 key={1}>
  //                 <input type='text'
  //                   className='w-full outline-none'
  //                   ref={pickUpRef}
  //                   defaultValue={pickUpAddr}
  //                   placeholder='Pick up address' />
  //               </Autocomplete>
  //             </>
  //           )}


  //           {isLoaded && (
  //             <>
  //               <form>
  //                 <Autocomplete

  //                   onPlaceChanged={handleDestChange}
  //                   key={1}>
  //                   <input type='text'
  //                     className='mt-7  w-full border hover:border-[#79BE1D] rounded-[20px]'
  //                     ref={dropRef}
  //                     defaultValue={dropAddr}
  //                     onChange={(e) => dispatch(setAddress({ inputField: e.target.value, flag: 'dropAddr' }))}
  //                     placeholder='Destination address' />
  //                 </Autocomplete>
  //               </form>
  //             </>
  //           )}

  //         </>
  //         <div className='bg-green-400 rounded-lg py-2 px-16 border-black border-2 w-10  flex justify-center '>
  //           <Link href='/map' >Proceed</Link>
  //         </div>
  //       </div>
  //       <div>
  //       </div>
  //     </div></div>
  //   )
  // }
  //navbar
  const userLogout = () => {
    dispatch(handleLogout())
    router.push('/')
  }
  const { isLoggedIn, userDetails } = useSelector(state => state.users)
  const content = (
    <div>
      <Link href="/profile" className='hover:text-green-500'>Profile</Link>
      <p onClick={userLogout} className='hover:cursor-pointer hover:text-red-500'>Logout</p>
    </div>
  );
  const vehiclesItems = [
    {
      key: 'Bike',
      label: <span>Bike <TwitterOutlined /></span>,

    },
    {
      key: 'Car',
      label: <span>Car <CarOutlined /></span>,

    },
    {
      key: 'Boat',
      label: <span>Boat <SmileOutlined /></span>,
    },
  ];
  //for map and simple card

  const [isEdit, setIsEdit] = useState(false)
  const [selectedVehicle, setSelectedVehicle] = useState('bike')
  // const handlePickUpChange = ()=> {
  //   dispatch(setAddress({inputField: pickUpRef.current.value, flag:'pickUpAddr'}))
  // }

  const distance = getDistance(
    pickUpCords,
    dropCords
  );
  // const handleDestChange = ()=> {
  //   dispatch(setAddress({inputField: destRef.current.value, flag:'dropAddr'}))
  // }
  const { pricePerUnitKm, basePrice, nightPricePercentile } = priceMapping[selectedVehicle.toLowerCase()]
  const generateCenter = () => {
    if (pickUpCords.lat) {
      return pickUpCords
    } else {
      return center
    }
  }
  const initialPrice = (pricePerUnitKm * (distance / 1000)) + basePrice

  const onLoad = marker => {
    console.log('marker: ', marker)
  }
  //usercard content
  const pickUpRef = useRef(null);
  const dropRef = useRef(null);

  const handlePickUpChange = () => {
    dispatch(setAddress({ inputField: pickUpRef.current.value, flag: 'pickUpAddr' }))
  }
  const handleDestChange = () => {
    dispatch(setAddress({ inputField: dropRef.current.value, flag: 'dropAddr' }))
  }


  return (
    <>
      <div className='w-screen h-10vh bg-black flex justify-between p-5 ' style={{
        borderBottom: '5px solid green ',
        borderRadius: '2px',
      }}>
        <div className='w-28 flex hover:cursor-pointer'><CustomLogo /></div>
        <div className=''>

          <Popover placement="bottom" title={userDetails?.fullName} content={content} trigger="click">

            <Avatar
              size="large"
              style={{
                backgroundColor: '#fde3cf',
                color: '#f56a00',
                fontSize: '1.5rem',
                marginRight: '2rem',
              }}
            >
              {userDetails?.fullName?.[0]}
            </Avatar>
          </Popover>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='flex '>
        <div ><MapView /></div>
      </div>

    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: What causes the markers to be updated?

Comment: Adding comments to your code or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like a working codesandbox would be great!

Comment: @Andy i am updating MarkerF using property draggable=true

Comment: You could try using useMemo for your `currentPosition` state variable to prevent everything else from rerendering. Also are you by any means using other products together with Google Maps APIs? You should check out the ToS with regards to this: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#:~:text=(e)%C2%A0No%20Use%20With%20Non%2DGoogle%20Maps.